# WINAPI keyboards detect other application hotkeys

Tags: winapi, keyboard, hotkeys

Goal : I want to know that the user did or did't press on some hotkeys that i want to know it, like i want to know he/she press Ctrl + N on chrome

i try to detect the application hotkeys, like maybe chrome Ctrl + N is open new tab.

How winapi can detect this?

i have seen some article that said WM_KEYUP + WM_KEYDOWN, but the wParam one times can get one WM_KEYUP or WM_KEYDOWN, how implement it ?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyBoardHookProc, hInstance, 0);
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, hInstance, 0);
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);}

KeyBoardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT cKey = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
     .................

    if(wParam == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        kp.HandlekeyboardInfo(lpszName, buffer);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: This makes next to no sense. Can you step back and tell us your actual goal. I'm quite confident that you have chosen the wrong solution.

Comment: I want to know that the user did or did't press on some hotkeys that i want to know it, like i want to know he/she press Ctrl + N on chrome

Comment: What has RegisterHotKey got to do with anything? That's not relevant here. You need to listen for CTRL going down, then N going down.

Comment: So the first time i tried wrong way.Thanks for giving the comment to me.  Is the any idea that can let me know how to listen CTRL going down and then N going.

Comment: Just detect those keys in your hook proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can do this. The easiest is probably to register a hotkey within your application and let windows notify you when the key combination is pressed.

[RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Another method would be to register a keyboard hook. All keypresses will be passed to your application, but you'll have to determine what keys were pressed. If you go this route, make sure to call CallNextHookEx().

[SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: now i'm using SetWindowsHookEx to do it, because the RegisterHotKey will cause original hotkey lost